# Minimum cooling flow without an outlet temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, cooling

I want to calculate the minimum cooling flow rate $\dot{m}$ for a stirred batch process. The stirrer heats up the reactor's content quite intensively, so first I  calculate the temperature of after the given process time $t$ and the dissipation energy $W_{Dis}$:

\begin{align*}
\frac{d H}{dt} &= W_{Dis} \\
\frac{m \cdot c_P \cdot dT}{dt} &= W_{Dis} \\
\vdots \\
T_{End} &= T_0 + \frac{W_{Dis }\cdot t}{m \cdot c_p}.
\end{align*}

Now I would proceed with the heat transfer through the steel wall into the surrounding cooling liquid. The problem is that the cooler is not a traditional pipe coil, rather a pillow plate cooling jacket.

Still the cooling stream $\dot{Q}_{Cooling}$ from the inside of the reactor to the cooling liquid I'd calculate to

\begin{align*}
\dot{Q}_{Cooling} &= k \cdot A \cdot \Delta T.
\end{align*}

where $k$ is the heat transfer coefficient and $A$ the heat transfer surface.

Normally with a given inlet and outlet temperature, I'd do an energy balance with the corresponding enthalpy $\dot{H}_{In}$ and $\dot{H}_{Out}$

\begin{align*}
\frac{dH}{dt} &= \dot{Q}_{Cooling} + \dot{H}_{In} - \dot{H}_{Out} \\
\frac{dH}{dt} &= k \cdot A \cdot \Delta T + \dot{m} \cdot c_p \cdot (T_{In} - T_{Out})
\end{align*}

and solve this equation for the desired mass flow $\dot{m}$.

But how would you calculate the mass flow without having an outlet temperature of the cooling system $T_{Out}$?

Comment: If you assume a mass fliw, what emperature do you get? Or, what temperature do you want?

Comment: I want to know the  minimal mass flow for a maximum reactor temperatur $T_{End}$ after the process, the outlet temperature is not important to me.